# VBA for loop; if cells are in range, insert range value

Tags: vba, excel

I am struggling trying to make this work. I have a list of dollar amounts, and I need to loop through them and identify those which fall into certain ranges.

**Current Data**

```
Name      Value     Range     
Bob       $1403
Julius    $11,425
Mike      $20,493
Lucas     $9,970
```

**Desired Output**

```
Name     Value     Range    
Bob      $1403     <$10,000
Julius   $11,425   $10,000-$50,000
Mike     $20,493   $10,000-$50,000
Lucas    $9,970    <$10,000
```

**Current Result**

```
Name     Value     <$10,000    
Bob      $1403     <$10,000
Julius   $11,425  
Mike     $20,493   
Lucas    $9,970
```

**Current Code**

```
Sub FindMatchingValue()
 Dim assetRange As Range
 Set assetRange = Range("B2:B5")
 Set nextRange = Range("C2:C5")
 For Each c In Worksheets("Single Audit").Range("B2:B5").Cells
    If c(i, 1).Value <= 10000 Then
        nextRange(c).Value = "<$10,000"
   Else
   If (c(i, 1).Value >= 10000) And (c(i, 1).Value <= 50000) Then
        nextRange(c).Value = "$10,000-$50,000"
    End If
    End If
  Next c
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is a shorter version:

```
Sub FindMatchingValue()
    With Worksheets("Single Audit").Range("C2:C5")
        .Formula = "=IF(B2<10000,""<$10,000"",IF(AND(B2>10000,B2<=50000),""$10,000-$50,000"",""""))"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

code above used formula to find result and `.Value = .Value` rewrites formulas with thouse results.

Or if you'd like to modify your code:

```
Sub FindMatchingValue2()
    Dim assetRange As Range
    Dim c As Range

    Set assetRange = Worksheets("Single Audit").Range("B2:B5")

    For Each c In assetRange
        If c.Value <= 10000 Then
            c.Offset(, 1).Value = "<$10,000"
        ElseIf (c.Value >= 10000) And (c.Value <= 50000) Then
            c.Offset(, 1).Value = "$10,000-$50,000"
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Why VBA for such a simple task?

Assuming Value start at B2, write the formula:

```
=LOOKUP(B2;{0;10000;50000.01};{"<$10,000";"$10,000-$50,000";">$50,000"})
```

And copy down

Depending on your regional settings you may need to replace arg separator ";" by ","

Comment: That's a good point. I was making this somewhat more complicated. Thank you!